# TypeScript tricky module not found error

Tags: typescript, import, ionic2, typescript2.0

I'm using `ionic 1` and thought it might be a good idea to change to TypeScript. Then of course I wanna use the `ionic-native` features.

- I tried to: `import {Calendar} from 'ionic-native';`
- but I got: `[ts] Cannot find module 'ionic-native'`.

So went to read the docs [How TypeScript resolves modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).
Docs says it tries to locate the module in following paths:

```
1. /root/node_modules/moduleB.ts
2. /root/node_modules/moduleB.tsx
3. /root/node_modules/moduleB.d.ts
4. /root/node_modules/moduleB/package.json (if it specifies a "typings" property)
5. /root/node_modules/moduleB/index.ts
6. /root/node_modules/moduleB/index.tsx
7. /root/node_modules/moduleB/index.d.ts
```

So I looked into my node_folders and see if one path matches:

```
node_modules
- ionic-native
-- dist
-- package.json
```

So I think number 4. should match, since the package.json contains:

```
"typings": "dist/es5/index.d.ts
```

But it's not working.

If I instead do:

```
import {Calendar} from '../../../node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/index';
```

it works but I do not want to do it like this in all files, that's way too complicated :/

---

Because I wanted to move forward, I searched for another way in the TypeScript docs. I also could read that you can put a `paths property for modules` in `tsconfig.json`

But the funny part of it is, if I put correct json it, it doesn't works:

```
"paths": {
  "ionic-native": ["node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/index.d.ts"]
}
```

When i put invalid json in it, it works (note the missing `"`):

```
"paths": {
  ionic-native: ["node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/index.d.ts"]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Dear downvoter, instead of downvoting you could have answered this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed a TS tutorial and just copied the `tsconfig.json`, but there are different types of modules and I had

```
"module": "system",
```

just replaced it with

```
"module": "commonjs",
```

and whooops, instantly everything works, like I ever wanted.